# Obtener mayor, menor y media en un vector de 30 números aleatorios

Tags: c

Tengo que realizar el siguiente ejercicio:

> Crear un vector de 30 números aleatorios, obtener la media, y el número mayor y menor en C.

Pero no sé cómo sacar la media y el número mayor y menor del vector de números aleatorios. Éste es el código que llevo hasta el momento:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void show(int b[], int tam){
  for (int i=0; i<tam; i++)
    printf(b[i], " ");
}

int main (){
  const tam 20;
  int a[tam];   
  for (int i=0; i<tam; i++)
    a[i] = 1 + rand() % 100;
  show(a, tam); // name and size

  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Para los tres casos necesitas un bucle, por lo que puedes hacer las tres cosas a la vez en el mismo bucle. Recorres los elementos del vector y en una variable vas acumulando su suma, en otra guardas el mayor encontrado hasta el momento (la inicializas con 0 por ejemplo, y si el elemento examinado es mayor, la actualizas) y en otra guardas el menor hasta el momento (similar a lo antes dicho, pero inicializando con el valor máximo posible). Al salir del bucle tienes ya el máximo y mínimo, y la media será la suma acumulada entre el número de elementos.

Answer (score -2):

siguiendo lo que necesitas y haciendo complementacio a lo que dijo el Maestro @abulafia te muestro como debe ser el ejemplo:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
  #include<conio.h>

  void show(int b[], int tam){

  for (int i=0; i<tam; i++)

    printf(b[i], " ");

  }

  int main (){

      const tam 20;
      int a[tam];   
      int suma;
      int mayor =0;
      int menor=9999999999999999;

      for (int j =0; j<tam; j++ ){

        a[j]=  1 + rand()% 100;
        //a cada vuelta cumulamos el valor obtenido
        suma= suma + a[j];

        //evaluamos si el numero es mayo y lo almacenamos en la variable
        if (a[j] > mayor) {
            mayor = a[j];
        }
        //evaluamos si el numero es menor y lo almacenamos
        if (a[j] < menor) {
            menor = a[j];
        }
      }
      //obtenemos la media dividiendo la suma total entre la cantidad de elementos
      double media = suma / a.length
      printf("La media es igual a: %d", media);
      printf("El numero mayor es: %d", mayor);
      printf("El numero menor es: %d", menor);


      show(a, tam);//name and size

      getch();
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Gracias por completar mi comentario, pero yo habia decidido intencionadamente no mostrarle la solución ya hecha, para que tuviera que pensarlo un poco. Es como se aprende a programar ;-) Cuando lo hubiera intentado y si se hubiera atascado, ya podría volver a preguntar con dudas más concretas.

Comment: Hoo!! pense que quizas era por falta de tiempo, Disculpas, pero si lo prefieres elimino la respuesta :) @abulafia

Comment: Como quieras, por mi no hace falta :-)

Comment: @srJJ si vas a hacerlo de nuevo lo recomendable es que lo hagas como wiki de comunidad :), asi la comunidad podra mejorarlo :)

Comment: @srJJ por favor, no utilices firmas o slogans en tus publicaciones. No aportan nada a la publicación y sólo añaden ruido.

Comment: Bueno señor, ya el dia de ayer me hiceron la recomendacion, la cual estare atento a no cometer ese error @gbianchi gracias... y Alvaro Montoro...